# Grep single value after match

Tags: json, bash, raspberry-pi

I have a file containing:

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"speed":0}}
```

How would I be able to grep "0" after "speed":"?

I have tried 'grep -o -P "speed":{1}', not what I am looking for.

Comment: Use `jq` if you work with json

Comment: @hek2mgl Not sure it's a json file. All values are not double-quoted.

Comment: Numbers don't need to be quoted in json

Comment: @hek2mgl You're right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `jq` (`sudo apt-get install jq` on raspbian) for this task.

```
echo '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"speed":0}}' | jq .result.speed
```

Result: `0`

---

Since you said in your question that you have a file "containing" this line, you might want to use grep first to get only the line you're interested in, otherwise `jq` might throw an error.

Example file:

```
abc
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"speed":0}}
123
```

Running `grep "speed" yourfile.txt | jq .result.speed` would output `0`.